# Make Post in django

Tags: python, django

How can you allow users to post something on the website using Django framework?

My views.py file :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['url']:
            post = models.Post()
            post.title 
            post.url 
            post.pub_date 
            post.author 
            post.save()
            return redirect('create')
    else:
        return render(request, 'posts/create.html')
```

my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and my create.html file:

```
<h1> Create Post</h1>
{% if error%}
{{ error }}
{% endif%}
<br />
<br />
<br />
<form  method='POST'  action="{% url 'create' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
Title:
<input type="text" name="title">
<br />
<br />
URL:
<br />
<input type="text" name="url">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

The problem is the post doesn't even show up in the admin panel and i also get this error

```
NameError at /posts/create/

name 'post' is not defined
```

thank you

Comment: Please post your full error.

Comment: Did you read the django docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/ Everything you need is explained there.

Comment: and pls clarify what you mean by "not showing in the admin panel"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your create method as below...

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('title') and request.POST.get('url'):

            title = request.POST.get('title') 
            url = request.POST.get('url')
            pub_date = request.POST.get('pub_date') 
            author = request.POST.get('author')
            post_obj = Post.objects.create(title=title, url=url, pub_date=pub_date, author=author) 

            return redirect('create')
    else:
        return render(request, 'posts/create.html')
```

Comment: Still this would be considered bad practice as there are no input validations?

Comment: Is this helpful to you?